# PHP: Sibling to child Multi-dimensional array within loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to transform an array's sibling elements into parent-child format.

The reason for having this particular format for embedding into graphical format.

I have tried couple of array functions like array_walk_recursive etc. and able to transform. But when i foresee the scenario for nth level then, it is actually breaking up.

So, scenario is to link-up the each index element with the next element as parent and make a part-child relation in nested version.
**Actual Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Student 1
            [parent] => null 
            [children] => Fail-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Student 2 
            [parent] => null
            [children] => Fail-2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Student 3 
            [parent] => null
            [children] => Pass
        )

)
```

**Expected Result**

```
          Array
          (
                [name] => Student 1
                [parent] => null 
                [children] => Array
                    (
                       [name] => Fail-1 
                       [parent] => Student 1
                       [children] => Array
                           (
                               [name] => Student 2 
                               [parent] => Fail-1 
                               [children] => Array
                                  (
                                      [name] => Fail-2 
                                      [parent] => Student 2 
                                      [children] => Array
                                          (
                                              [name] => Student 3 
                                              [parent] => Fail-2
                                              [children] => Array
                                                  (
                                                     [name] => Pass 
                                                     [parent] => null
                                                     [children] => null
                                                  )
                                          )
                                  )

                           )
                    )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'name' => 'Student 1',
        'parent' => NULL,
        'children' => 'Fail-1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Student 2',
        'parent' => NULL,
        'children' => 'Fail-2'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Student 3',
        'parent' => NULL,
        'children' => 'Pass'
    ]
];

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    $entry['children'] = [
        'name' => $entry['children'],
        'parent' => $entry['name'],
        'children' => null
    ];
    $output[] = $entry;
});

do {
    $toBeMoved = array_pop($output);
    $toBeMovedTo = &$output[count($output)-1];
    $toBeMoved['parent'] = $toBeMovedTo['children']['name'];
    $toBeMovedTo['children']['children'] = $toBeMoved;
} while (1 < count($output));
print_r($output);
```

The output of above code is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Student 1
            [parent] =>
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Fail-1
                    [parent] => Student 1
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Student 2
                            [parent] => Fail-1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Fail-2
                                    [parent] => Student 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Student 3
                                            [parent] => Fail-2
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Pass
                                                    [parent] => Student 3
                                                    [children] =>
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

That is the output you posted as "expected", apart from the `parent` element in the last entry. The value `null` you proposed for that element is illogical in my eyes which is why I ignored it. It would be trivial however to implement a final exception assignment for that element, though.